# Why are special chars rendered badly in the page?

Tags: php, character-encoding

I wrote a PHP script which gets a text input as input from a page. The code is only this, for now:

```
<?php
include("../Includes/Database.php");
mysql_select_db('...', $db3);
$originalText=$_POST['text'];
echo $originalText;
?>
```

The code works fine for normal input (printable ASCII), but not for special characters such as `é`, `д`, `φ`... For example, inputting `Stack Overflow` outputs `Stack Overflow`, while `Δημοκρατία` returns `Î”Î·Î¼Î¿ÎºÏÎ±Ï„Î¯Î±`. It doesn't work for Extended ASCII, either: `même` returns `mÃªme`.
I don't need full Unicode support [although it'd be good], just extended ASCII, as the input text will be in Italian (which uses `à`, `è`, `é`, `ì`, `ò` and `ù`).

[Exactly, `Δημοκρατία` uses Unicode characters, as it is Greek for "democracy"; `même` uses Extended ASCII, as it is French for "same" (`ê` is Extended ASCII)]

Comment: What is the encoding of your page and your PHP scripts?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, solved adding `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to achieve this is declaring the encoding of the page, either modifying the HTTP header or using a `<meta>` tag. In this case, the `UTF-8` encoding will fit the requirements.

HTTP header:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

HTML (*will be overridden by the HTTP header*):

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```